# Why vscode is importing packages from typescript cache

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code

I've started a react-native project generated using the cli. The app seems to be working just fine but i've notice that the import points to typescript cache instead of local node_modules. I'm not even using typescript.

IDE: vscode 1.19.3

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

> module
>   "/Users/MyMac/Library/Caches/typescript/2.6/node_modules/@types/react/index"

Comment: @types is a collection of typescript definition packages and not the actual library itself. So in your case it is only loading the type definitions for React from this directory. I'd guess vscode does this to provide intellisense even when you're not using TypeScript.

Comment: Only problem is that it breaks my app every time it does.. (react-native)... the relative paths don't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected for JavaScript. These `@types` files power VS Code IntelliSense for npm modules such as `react`. The `react` module itself will still be imported from your local `node_modules`

See our documentation on [Automatic type acquisition](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_automatic-type-acquisition) for more details

Comment: Isn't it possible for this to be misleading? For example, VS Code won't show an import error for a package that isn't installed locally in the module if it just so happens to be installed in the `.../Caches/typescript/4.0/node_modules/@types/` directory?

Comment: I know it's an old question but... Can't this behavior cause some problems? I just encountered one. My React Native project uses React 17, and because the TS cache references @types/react for React 18, I get type errors everywhere. Didn't find much about how to solve that, either on SO or in VSCode's GH issues.

Comment: @benito, Check the `typescript.disableAutomaticTypeAcquisition` config option

Comment: @mmomtchev I'd eventually figured it out, out of bare necessity, but thanks!