# Stop VSCode converting javascript imports to typescript cache on file rename

Tags: javascript, typescript, intellisense, visual-studio-code

Whenever I rename a local file in VSCode, it re-writes the javascript import of external libraries to be typescript imports for a load of files.

I go from

```
import localFn from './localFile';
import angular from 'angular';
import { fooBar } from 'misc-package';
```

to

```
import localfn from './myLovelyLocalFile';
import angular from '../../../../../.cache/typescript/2.9/node_modules/angular';
import { fooBar } from '../../../../../.cache/typescript/2.9/node_modules/misc-package';
```

And this is across all package that contain angular, misc-package and anything else it thinks it has in typescript.

Is there a way to prevent this?

It looks like this is an issue <sup>[1](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/53754), [2](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/54634)</sup> on the VSCode github repo.

Comment: This looks related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48480676/why-vscode-is-importing-packages-from-typescript-cache

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your settings in Vs code :

```
"javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "never",
```

Comment: Won't that prevent changing the name of imports for files I do want renamed? So if I'm doing `import { fooComponent } from './components/barComponent'` and I rename the file to `fooComponent`, would that not prevent the import to change?

Comment: it prevents that, i don't think there is a setting only for external librairies

Comment: Ivan, it was more that I don't use typescript at all. It looks like it's defaulting to that though.