# react import looks inside node modules cache instead of inside node modules folder?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

Using VS code to code a React app and getting `Module not found: Can't resolve zxcvbn`, turns out it's looking inside a cached node modules folder on the system instead of the node modules folder inside of the project.

`module "/home/someuser/.cache/typescript/4.2/node\_modules/@types/zxcvbn/index"`

Is this the cause of the module resolve error when building the react app? Why is it not pointing to the installed package inside the node modules folder within the project?

Other packages such as `react` point to the `react` module inside the node modules folder within the project so it's not clear why all the imports don't just point to inside the node modules

Comment: Interesting, I've never noticed it using a cache folder like that before.

Comment: Can you try deleting the node modules completely and installing them again.

Comment: Try running `npm cache clean`

Comment: Also see this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48480676/why-vscode-is-importing-packages-from-typescript-cache